# FTDI LibMPSSE SPI

Tags: linux, x86-64, reverse-engineering, ftdi

I recently purchased the FTDI C232HM-DDHSL-0 USB cable for use with SPI and I2C devices; my goal is to read the memory from an SPI memory chip that I removed from a router. However, I am having issues getting the libMPSSE library & 2xx drivers to send signals to a connected device.**I hooked the leads of the C232 up to a Saleae logic analyzer and saw that no signals were being output!**

Useful links for this question:

- FTDI C232HM-DDHSL-0 (purchase):
  https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBMPSSE.htm
- C232HM-DDHSL-0 data sheet:
  https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_C232HM_MPSSE_CABLE.PDF
- Memory Chip data sheet: https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7370/MX25L6406E,%203V,%2064Mb,%20v1.9.pdf
- 2xx drivers: https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm
- MPSSE SPI library:
  https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI.htm

I am using a **Debian x86_64** machine. The MPSSE SPI download only had the i386 version of the library, so I downloaded the MPSSE SPI source (https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI.htm) and built the x86_64 bit version. There were no build errors or warnings.

I copied libftd2xx.so and libMPSSE.so to /usr/local/lib.

I plugged the cable in, then removed the following kernel modules:

- ftdi_sio  <-- Readme says to take take out
- usbserial  <-- Readme says to take out
- usb_wann  <-- Needed to remove to take out usbserial
- qcserial  <-- Needed to remove to take out usbserial

At this point I was hoping that my set up was done correctly.

I connected 6x cables to the 8 pin memory chip:

- VCC <--> red lead
- Ground <--> black lead
- Chip select <--> brown lead
- Data in <--> green
- serial clock <--> orange
- Data out <--> yellow

I did not connect hold and write protect pins on the memory chip. Recall my goal is to read the memory out of the chip, and the waveform for the read did not show those pins were necessary.

I am using this program:

```
/* Standard C libraries */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include "ftd2xx.h"
#include "libMPSSE_spi.h"

FT_HANDLE ftHandle;

uint8 tx_buffer[4096] = {0};
uint8 rx_buffer[4096] = {0};

int main()
{
    uint8 i = 0;
    int sizeToTransfer = 0;
    int sizeTransfered = 0;
    FT_STATUS status = FT_OK;
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE devList = {0};
    ChannelConfig channelConf = {0};

    channelConf.ClockRate = 30000000; // 30Mhz
    channelConf.LatencyTimer = 75;
    channelConf.configOptions = SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0 | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS3 | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_ACTIVELOW;
    channelConf.Pin = 0x00000000;/*FinalVal-FinalDir-InitVal-InitDir (for dir 0=in, 1=out)*/


    //
    // Open the channel and dump some information
    //
    status = SPI_GetChannelInfo(0,&devList);
    if (status != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("SPI_GetChannelInfo failed, status = %d\n", status);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Flags=0x%x\n",devList.Flags);
    printf("Type=0x%x\n",devList.Type);
    printf("ID=0x%x\n",devList.ID);
    printf("LocId=0x%x\n",devList.LocId);
    printf("SerialNumber=%s\n",devList.SerialNumber); // TODO: Why blank?
    printf("Description=%s\n",devList.Description);
    printf("ftHandle=0x%p\n",devList.ftHandle);/*is 0 unless open*/


    //
    // Open channel 0 
    //
    status = SPI_OpenChannel(0,&ftHandle);
    if (status != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("SPI_OpenChannel failed, status = %d\n", status);
        return -1;
    }

    //
    // Initialize the channel: See configuration structure at top of main()
    //
    status = SPI_InitChannel(ftHandle,&channelConf);
    if (status != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("SPI_InitChannel failed, status = %d\n", status);
        return -1;
    }

    //
    // Send the read command (0x03), and read what we get in our receive buffer
    //
    sizeToTransfer=8;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    tx_buffer[0] = 0x03;
    status = SPI_ReadWrite(ftHandle, rx_buffer, tx_buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered, 
            SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES|SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE|SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE);
    if (status != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("SPI_ReadWrite failed, status = %d\n", status);
        return -1;
    }

    //
    // Dump the receive buffer to see if we got anything.
    //
    printf("Size transfered = %d\n", sizeTransfered);
    i = 0;
    while (i < sizeTransfered)
    {
        printf("%02x",rx_buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }   
    printf("\n");

    //
    // Cleanup
    //
    status = SPI_CloseChannel(ftHandle);
    if (status != FT_OK)
    {   
        printf("SPI_CloseChannel failed, ret = %d\n", status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To make and run the program:

```
To compile: gcc read_memory.c -lMPSSE -ldl
To run: sudo ./a.out
```

My output is:

```
// The driver can at least detect the cable.
Flags=0x2
Type=0x8
ID=0x4036001
LocId=0x204
SerialNumber=
Description=USB <-> Serial
ftHandle=0x(nil)
Size transfered = 8

// Junk in the receive buffer
ff037fffffffffff
```

Whether I keep the memory chip connected or disconnected I get the same junk in the receive buffer. I see no LEDs light up on the cable or anything to indicate it is "working." I have tried SPI_Write() and SPI_Read() and get similar behavior. I tested on an Ubuntu VM (running on Windows host) and saw the exact same behavior.

I am really excited to get this to work so if anyone can help me with what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You could try to verify if the device is functional: Disconnect the slave device (mem). If you have a scope check if you see a clock signal during transmission (be aware that the MPSSE has some built in sleep(2) in its code base - this means you need proper trigger setting to see something - especially with a clock of 30MHz). Additionally you can check the read functionality by connecting the MISO to either GND or VDD and start a read. If the response is all zero for GND and VDD, the reading should be functional.

Comment: Thanks for the response Christian. I connected the cable's MISO to ground and saw 0's in my buffer! I am not sure what VDD is, but I connected to 3.5 volt VCC and saw all F's, which I expect. I also hooked the MISO to the MOSI and saw exactly what I intended to send.

Comment: I am optimistic that my cable is fine. Thank you for the debugging suggestion! Perhaps the issue may be a state that the memory chip is, or an incompatibility: The max clock that the chip operates at is 33MHz but I am using 30MHz (cable's max) for example. I don't have a scope but I do have a saleae that I will try again

Comment: Try a lower clock frequency. Check if you selected the right CS pin, phase and polarity. I did not read the mem datasheet in detail but I noticed that the interface is not really SPI compatible as the SI pin can act as input AND output to effectively double the transmission rate.  So better check under which circumstances the interface could be SPI like.

Comment: I set clock to 50KHz and the wave form looked much better. Chip select, MOSI, and clock all looked as I hoped. However, at that clock rate, MISO stayed high. When I change the clock back to 30MHz I see some non high Bytes for the first few, then high after. Is it possible this thing requires me to operate at 33MHz for a read (my cable's maximum is 30MHz)? In the data sheet it says reads are a max of 33MHz... Also I started messing around with trying to change it's mode in the case it is in a weird state. No differences in MISO yet, but will keep putzing :)

Comment: The datasheet actually states that the clk speed can range from "DC" to 33 MHz  IIRC. So no need to go for the high clock speeds at all.

Comment: @donsiuch did you create your own Makefile to build libMPSSE for 64-bit Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Set device first to MPSSE mode, and it should work. See quite minimum (Python) example below based on FTD2XX library only (tested in Windows). LibMPSSE is not required to run simple SPI. Data can be read by `s = dev.read(nbytes)`, where nbytes is byte count. Find more information in nice tutorial: [Driving an SPI device using MPSSE](https://iosoft.blog/2018/12/05/ftdi-python-part-3/)

```
import ftd2xx
OPS = 0x03                                  # Bit mask for SPI clock and data out
OE = 0x08                                   # CS

dev = ftd2xx.open(0)                        # open first available device
if dev:
    dev.setTimeouts(1000, 1000)
    dev.setBitMode(OPS, 2)                  # bit mask, MPSSE mode
    dev.write(bytes((0x86, 59, 0)))         # set SCK to 100kHz
    dev.write(bytes((0x80, 0, OE + OPS)))   # CS low
    data = 0x55,
    n = len(data) - 1
    dev.write(bytes(((0x11, n % 256, n // 256) + data))) # write SPI data
    dev.write(bytes((0x80, OE, OE + OPS)))  # CS high
    dev.close()
```